# Return records that do not have a value in a certain field

Tags: mysql

I have a Jira system that we need to do some user cleanup for. I'm blanking out on how to write this particular query. The table in question looks like this, where CHILD_ID is a username and PARENT_ID is a group name.

```
CHILD_ID   |   PARENT_ID
=============================
Jane          admins
Jane          users
John          users
```

So there are multiple records per person; one for each group they belong to. I need to return a list of CHILD_ID values that *don't* have a record for the admin group - so for the example, I'd want to return John only.

I've tried `select child_id from my_table where parent_id <> admins`, but that still returns the Jane record for the users group. I know this is something I've done before, but can't seem to remember how, and can't even figure out how to word a google search for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you could simply use an in query:

```
SELECT CHILD_ID FROM <your_table> WHERE CHILD_ID NOT IN (SELECT CHILD_ID FROM <your_table> WHERE PARENT_ID = 'admins');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grouping and a conditional aggregate:

```
select child_id 
from my_table
group by child_id
having count(case when parent_id = 'admins' then 1 end) = 0
```